# Complex manifold mapping to a Riemann surface it contains

Tags: complex-geometry

Let $\Sigma \subset M$ be a compact Riemann surface of genus $g\geq 2$ in a compact complex manifold. If there is a non-trivial map $M\to \Sigma$ is $M$ a direct product of $\Sigma$ and another manifold?

Comment: I presume u can get a counterexample by taking a non trivial extension, $V$, of $\mathcal{O}$ by itself and taking the projective bundle $\mathbb{P}(V)$. The sub $\mathcal{O}$ gives you the section.

Comment: In such a counterexample, the non-trivial map is even a retraction (i.e., is identity on $\Sigma$). That is, a retract need not be a direct factor.

Comment: Is there an example with compact complex manifolds where there is a surjective map but no retract?

Answer (score 4):

As requested, an example where there is no retract:

Take $E$ an elliptic curve, and $C$ a smooth curve of genus $\geq 2$ in $E \times E$. Take $D$ a ramified double cover of $C$, and let $M$ be the quotient of $D \times E \times E$ by the product of the involution on $D$ over $C$ and translation by a point of order $2$ on the first copy of $E$. This product involution has no fixed points so the quotient is smooth (and compact).

Then $M$ maps to $C$ by projection onto the first factor. It contains $E \times E$ (the fiber of this projection onto any unramified point) and thus contains $C$.

But there is no retract/ section, since that would pull back to be a section of $D \times E \times E \to D$ invariant under the involution, which means restricting to a ramified fiber we would get a point of $E \times E$ invariant under translation by a point of order $2$, which is impossible.